# How to click color patch

Tags: android, android-imageview, bitmapimage, android-color

I have an image with  the different color patches.This image is attached to image view

[image]

If I tap on the blue patch it should go to BlueActivity, green to GreenActivity similarly for other two colors.These color vary from deep to light in the irregular manner.If it is fixed color without any shade I can get the color on the touch of Image and proceed but can't do same here.
I tried drawing overlay using frameLayout on the top of this image but the solution does not work because in android we have device with n number of resolution.
So what should I do find which color I have clicked?

Comment: This may help you https://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/

Comment: @KetanAhir Already I have tried it but problem is to differentiate between let's say red and dark red if the image has more colors

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to set `OnTouchListener` on `ImageView`, then calculate position of touched pixel from `MotionEvent` using `ImageView` scale and read pixel color values. Then you can decide if touch event occurred on red / green / blue part of image and act accordingly:

http://android-er.blogspot.ru/2012/10/get-touched-pixel-color-of-scaled.html

On the upside you get non-rectangular touch points corresponding to what really was pressed, on downside it may be difficult to differentiate between let's say red and dark red if image has more colors. Also compressed image may have slightly different colors depending on touched pixel. One way to handle this would be to average n pixels around clicked position and then decide what was clicked.

Comment: Already I have tried it but problem is to differentiate between let's say red and dark red if the image has more colors.